# Adding Quantity box to products list magento

Tags: html, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.I have added the extension called featured product scroller.In that extension they are not providing Qty box.Now i am trying to [add qty box to the product](http://blog.hiremagentodeveloper.com/ecommerce/add-quantity-box-on-product-listing-page.html) by using following link

But problem is if i change the qty to 5 and add to cart its still adding 1 to shopping cart on every click of add to cart button.How to resolve this

And the code Looks like this

```
<span class="fadd">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>">       <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?> 
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" class="input-text qty"/> 
<?php endif; ?> 

<br /> 
                                                       <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation(' <?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                                                       </form>
                                                  </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add quantity box on Product Listing Page you'll need to edit `app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` file

1. Find the line below:

   `<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>`
2. Replace it with:

   `<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
    <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
    </form>`